# RODBC not available any more not supported not in R cran list

Tags: r, rodbc

Hi I want to connect to Oracle with R,
But as I see RODBC is not supported by R anymore.

Any help or comments about that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROracle` another r package which is a wrapper for `DBI` that is Oracle aware so long as you have Oracle Instant Client installed on your computer :

```
library(ROracle)
driver <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(driver, ....) #where the elipses are the traditional connction parameters ports, hosts, users passwords etc...
```

[You can read all about it right on Cran:](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/ROracle.pdf)

Comment: Yes, that would work also. I have not had great experiences with heavily intensive JavaVM packages and applications. But it will work if you get everything properly installed.